# translate don't work

Tags: symfony, yaml

I have the following code in config.yml:

```
framework:
#esi:             ~
translator:     { fallback: pt_BR }
secret:          %secret%
charset:         UTF-8
router:          { resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/config/routing.yml" }
form:            true
csrf_protection: true
validation:      { enable_annotations: true }
templating:      { engines: ['twig'] } #assets_version: SomeVersionScheme
session: 
    default_locale: pt_BR
    auto_start: true
```

In `MyBundle/Resources/translations` my file is: `MyBundle.pt_BR.yml`.

And one example of translate in the file is:

`form_my_height: "Altura"`

In my Form:

`$builder->add('height')`

When I clear cache and refresh page first time, the translation is load, but when I go to the other page it stops running.

Comment: Why are you loading services through config.yml?  Your bundle services should be loaded via the DI container  (Look at MyBundle/DependencyInjection/MyBundleExtension.php)

Comment: But even being loaded by DI, I have the same problem: The translate not load...

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  You're trying to use translations?

Comment: Yes. I thought it had to do with this error but not. I can't load the file of translation. When I clear cache, in first time refresh it load, but when I go to other page the translation stops running.

Comment: Wouldn't be able to be of much help without seeing the code you're using to translate messages, as well as the name of your translation file, and the contents.  Ensure that the default locale is set, and that your translation file contains the corresponding locale in the name(IE locale: en -- translations.en.xml) Have you followed the directions in the docs? http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/translation.html

Comment: Thx for help! I edited the question with codes, if can help me..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps try:

```
$builder->add('height', 'text', array('label' => 'form_my_height', 'translation_domain' => 'MyBundle'));
```

Answer (score 1):

or you can let the template translate your labels

php:

```
$builder->add('height', 'text', array('label' => 'form_my_height');
```

twig:

```
{{ form_label(form.height)|trans }}
{{ form_widget(form.height) }}
{{ form_errors(form.height) }}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have to go:

```
$builder->add($this->get('translator')->trans('form_my_height'))
```

If you're in a controller, if not you need to pass the translator service reference, and:

```
$builder->add($translator->trans('form_my_height'))
```